# Having trouble in generating PDF Symfony 3

Tags: php, pdf, twig, symfony

I followed a tutorial about knpsnappybundle to use pdf in symfony3 but the problem is that i need to pass an array of values to the pdf page so i can get a full page like the original one

here is the controller:

```
public function pdfAction(){
    $html = $this->renderView('@Recommendation/Recommendation/payment-successful.html.twig');

    $filename = sprintf('test.pdf', date('Y-m-d'));

    return new Response(
        $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html),
        200,
        [
            'Content-Type'        => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition' => sprintf('inline; filename="%s"', $filename),

        ]
    );

}
```

here is picture of the normal page with the PRINT button code :

```
<a href="{{ path('payment_pdf') }}"><button>PRINT</button></a>
```

and the route :

```
payment_pdf:
path:     /payment_pdf
defaults: { _controller: "RecommendationBundle:Recommendation:pdf"}
```

a picture of my original page:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MBEt.png

and now the picture of the pdf generated:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqs2x.png

you see that the table is empty !

sorry can't display the images

the twig file :

```html
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yourjavascript.com/12191816011/success.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.iconj.com/ico/f/k/fksvrhslsa.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yourjavascript.com/11396113712/jquery-ajax-deprecated-dimensions-effects-offset-wrap-min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/6dgxerbf1p6p8zl/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<html>


<div class="pf-checkout-container pf-success-page">
    <h1 class="pf-green">Payment Successful</h1>
    <p class="pf-processed-msg">Your payment has been processed! Details of the transaction are included below:</p>
    <div class="pf-total-col">
        <span class="pf-total-paid">Amount Paid</span>
        <div class="pf-total-wrapper">
            <span class="pf-total-label">Total:</span>
            <span class="pf-total-amount pf-green" id="pf-total-amount">$00.00</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="pf-success-details">
        <p>Thank you for your purchase. Be sure to check us out on Facebook & Twitter!</p>
        <div class="pf-success-info">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span class="pf-value-name">Name:</span>
                    <span id="pf-full-name" class="pf-value">{{ app.user.username }}</span>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <span class="pf-value-name">Auth Code:</span>
                    <span  class="pf-value">{{app.user.salt}}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <br>
            <br>
            <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="10" style="font-family:'Myriad Pro' ">

                <tr>
                    <th width="43%" align="left">Product Name</th>
                    <th width="10%">Unit Price</th>
                    <th width="10%">Quantity</th>
                    <th width="12%">Total</th>
                </tr>

                {% if livres is defined %}
                    {% for l in livres %}
                        <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class=" product-detail">
                            <td valign="top">{{ l.titre }}</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">{{ l.prix }} DT</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">{{ l.quantite}}</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">{{ l.prix}} DT</td>
                        </tr>


                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}

            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- | PUT YOUR COMPANY LOGO HERE | -->

        <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    </div>
    <div class="pf-payment-buttons">
        <!-- | PUT YOUR LINK HERE | -->
        <button>Back to Store</button>

        <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    </div>

   <a href="{{ path('payment_pdf') }}"><button>PRINT</button></a>

   <div class="pf-footer">

            <img src="https://stripe.com/img/v3/home/social.png" />

    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

My Full Controller File:

```
class RecommendationController extends Controller
```

{

```
public function afficheAction()
{


    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $recommendation = $em->getRepository("MainBundle:Recommendation")->findAll();
    return $this->render("RecommendationBundle:Recommendation:book_detail.html.twig", array('recom' => $recommendation));
}

public function afficheparidAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em1 = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


    $livre = $em->getRepository('MainBundle:Livre')->find($id);
    $recommendation = $em1->getRepository('MainBundle:Recommendation')->findAll();


    return $this->render('RecommendationBundle:Recommendation:book_detail.html.twig', array(
        'livre' => $livre, 'recom' => $recommendation
    ));
}


public function AjoutAction($id)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $livre = $em->getRepository('MainBundle:Livre')->find($id);
    $rec = new Recommendation();
    if (isset($_POST['review'])) {
        $rec->setIdUtilisateur($user);
        $rec->setContenu($_POST['review']);
        $rec->setIdLivre($livre);
        $em->persist($rec);
        $em->flush();
```

//            return $this->redirectToRoute("recommendation_bookid");
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('recommendation_new', array('id' => $id)));

```
    }
    $em1 = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $recommendation = $em1->getRepository('MainBundle:Recommendation')->findAll();
    return $this->render("RecommendationBundle:Recommendation:new_rec.html.twig", array('livre' => $livre, 'id' => $id, 'recom' => $recommendation));


}


public function DeleteAction($id_r, $id_l)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $rec = $em->getRepository('MainBundle:Recommendation')->find($id_r);
    $livre = $em->getRepository('MainBundle:Livre')->find($id_l);
    $em->remove($rec);
    $em->flush();
    $em1 = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('recommendation_new', array('livre' => $livre, 'id' => $livre->getId())));
}


public function UpdateAction($id_r,$id_l)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $rec = $em->getRepository('MainBundle:Recommendation')->find($id_r);
    $em->remove($rec);
    $em->flush();
    $livre = $em->getRepository('MainBundle:Livre')->find($id_l);


    if (isset($_POST['review'])) {
        $rec->setId($id_r);
        $rec->setIdUtilisateur($user);
        $rec->setContenu($_POST['review']);
        $rec->setIdLivre($livre);
        $em->persist($rec);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('recommendation_new', array('id' => $id_l)));
}
}


public function FindAction($id_l,$id_r)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em1 = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


    $rec = $em->getRepository('MainBundle:Recommendation')->find($id_r);
    $livre = $em1->getRepository('MainBundle:Livre')->find($id_l);


    return $this->render('RecommendationBundle:Recommendation:edit_rec.html.twig', array('rec' => $rec, 'livre' =>$livre));

}

public function bookAction()
{
    return $this->render('RecommendationBundle:Recommendation:book_detail.html.twig');
}




public function cartAction($id)
{if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
    $_SESSION['cart']=array();}

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $livre = $em->getRepository('MainBundle:Livre')->find($id);
   // if (isset($_SESSION['book'])) {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = $livre;


    $cart=$_SESSION['cart'];
```

return $this->render('RecommendationBundle:Recommendation:cart.html.twig', array('id'=>$id,'livres'=>$cart));

```
}

public function emptycartAction()
{
    //if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
    $cart=$_SESSION['cart'];


    return $this->render('RecommendationBundle:Recommendation:cart.html.twig',array('livres'=>$cart));
```

}

```
public function removebookcartAction($id)
{
    // {if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])){


    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]);
   $cart=$_SESSION['cart'];
  // return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('recommendation_cart_affiche', array('livres' => $cart)));
```

return $this->redirectToRoute('recommendation_cart_show',array('livres'=>$cart));
//return $this->render('RecommendationBundle:Recommendation:cart.html.twig',array('id'=>1,'livres' => $cart) );

```
}

public function showAction(){
  //  if(!empty($_SESSION['cart']))
    $livres=$_SESSION['cart'];
    return $this->render('RecommendationBundle:Recommendation:cart.html.twig',array('livres'=>$livres));


}
public function okAction($cart){
    $cart=$_SESSION['cart'];


    return $this->render('RecommendationBundle:Recommendation:payment-successful.html.twig',array('livres'=>$cart));
```

}

```
public function pdfAction($cart){
   // $cart=$_SESSION['cart'];
    $html = $this->renderView('@Recommendation/Recommendation/payment_pdf.html.twig',array('livres'=>$cart));

    $filename = sprintf('test.pdf', date('Y-m-d'));

    return new Response(
        $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html),
        200,
        [
            'Content-Type'        => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition' => sprintf('inline; filename="%s"', $filename),
        ]
    );

}
```

My Routes :

> recommendation_bookid:
>       path:     /book_detail/{id}
>       defaults: { _controller: "RecommendationBundle:Recommendation:afficheparid" }
>   recommendation_book:
>       path:     /book_detail
>       defaults: { _controller: "RecommendationBundle:Recommendation:affiche" }
>   recommendation_new:
>       path:     /book_detail/{id}/new
>       defaults: { _controller: "RecommendationBundle:Recommendation:Ajout" }
>   recommendation_delete:
>       path:     /book_detail/{id_l}/{id_r}/delete
>       defaults: { _controller: "RecommendationBundle:Recommendation:Delete" }
>   recommendation_edit:
>       path:     /book_detail/{id_l}/{id_r}/edit
>       defaults: { _controller: "RecommendationBundle:Recommendation:Update" }
>   recommendation_find:
>       path:     /book_detail/{id_l}/{id_r}/find
>       defaults: { _controller: "RecommendationBundle:Recommendation:Find" }
>   recommendation_cart:
>       path:     /book_detail/{id}/cart
>       defaults: { _controller: "RecommendationBundle:Recommendation:cart" }
>   recommendation_empty:
>       path:     /emptycart
>       defaults: { _controller: "RecommendationBundle:Recommendation:emptycart" }
>   recommendation_cart_remove:
>       path:     /remove_book/{id}
>       defaults: { _controller: "RecommendationBundle:Recommendation:removebookcart" }
>   recommendation_cart_show:
>       path:     /remove_book
>       defaults: { _controller: "RecommendationBundle:Recommendation:show"}
>   payment_ok:
>       path:     /payment_success
>       defaults: { _controller: "RecommendationBundle:Recommendation:ok"}

payment_pdf:
    path:     /payment_pdf
    defaults: { _controller: "RecommendationBundle:Recommendation:pdf"}

Comment: What does clicking on `PRINT` show?

Comment: it shows the pdf page
it takes me to the route payment_pdf which has the action of generating the pdf page like mentionned above

Comment: Can you please show your twig file `payment-successful.html.twig` before and after you made changes. Or the current one if you don't have the old one.

Comment: i updated my post with the twig file

Comment: Do I not even get 1 upvote for helping out???

Comment: sorry i'm new on stackoverflow :) didn't think about it

Comment: Now is the time to start thinking about it, otherwise people won't help you out ;-) Take a hint!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think all you need to do is pass in your `livres` variable from the controller. I don't know what it's called, maybe `$livres`?

So like this:

```
public function pdfAction(){
    $html = $this->renderView('@Recommendation/Recommendation/payment-successful.html.twig', array(
        'livres'  => $livres
    ));

    $filename = sprintf('test.pdf', date('Y-m-d'));

    return new Response(
        $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html),
        200,
        [
            'Content-Type'        => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition' => sprintf('inline; filename="%s"', $filename),
        ]
    );
}
```

I think that should do it.

Comment: Sorry, you might need to pass `livres` in as a parameter to the route `pdfAction`. I'm not certain how you want your controller to work.

Comment: i did pass the livres as cart like this : 
<a href="{{ path('payment_pdf',{'cart':livres }) }}"><button>PRINT</button></a>

and in the controller i did what u told me :
public function pdfAction($cart){
    $html = $this->renderView('@Recommendation/Recommendation/payment-successful.html.twig', array(
        'livres'  => $cart
    ));
am i right ?
But it not working , i'm getting an empty table as usual

Comment: Then can you try the debug URL, by appending `app_dev.php` to the URL. Also do a dump of `livres` like this in twig: {{ dump(livres) }} and see if is empty. A dump will give a 500 error in production - just letting you know.

Comment: i'm already using app_dev.php but after adding {{dump(livres)}} i'm getting NULL ! it seems that my array is not passing

Comment: And this is the exact problem you need to solve! You can update you post or add a new question if you still need help.

Comment: You should give me an upvote for helping you out though, otherwise you would not know that is the problem.

Comment: just to let you know the livres varibale is a session array : $_SESSION['cart'] and i'm logged in .
i created another page now with the same source code of payment-successful.html.twig and tried to change like this.
renderView('@Recommendation/Recommendation/payment_pdf.html.twig', array(
        'livres'  => $livres));
but not working
i dnt why when i try to pass the array it takes null value ..

Comment: Please update your post or create a new one and show your `full` controller code so I can see what's going on.

Comment: i think the problem might comes from the pdfAction, there no command to send an array 
the first line is taking a view and putting it in $html and then it returns a response !! there is no way to send the array ?? before generating the pdf !?

Answer (score 0):

Read this:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

This is how sessions should be done in Symfony. You'll need to change some things...

Comment: i'm not having any trouble with my sessions , the $_session array is working fun ! but the pdfaction is not sending anything !! there is no command in the controller that sends values , it only gets the view

Comment: But $cart is empty! so something else is wrong. Suggest you figure that out! I can't help till you try something.

Answer (score -1):

***FIXED:***

i didn't need to pass the array as a parameter!
i just declared a variable like this : $cart = $_SESSION['cart'] ($_SESSION['cart'] is the array i use to store my vars) in my pdfController and pass it directly:
 $html = $this->renderView('@Recommendation/Recommendation/payment-pdf.html.twig', array(
        'livres'  => $cart
    ));

i'm working with a SESSION array so it's considered like a global variable :)